# Possible Firewall Issue

Tags: proxy, firewall, python

WHen I try to access the internet through IE with the follwing proxy details , I am able to access ineternet succcesfully

```
Proxy : MyProxy , Port: 88
```

But when I try to access the same programatically in python i.e :

```
proxies = {"http":"http://uname:psw@MyProxy:88"}
url = "http://www.google.com"
headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxies)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)    
req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

I get an error

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

I'm assuming it has got something to do with Firewall. But why does it work for one and not for the other . ALso are there any possible workarounds?